# how to remove date from DateTime C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I need just the time part of DateTime - HH:mm. How can I remove the rest? Can I do it in razor View:

```
 @Html.DisplayFor(m=>m.model.MondayStart)
```

or do I have to add some kind of attribute in the model?

```
 public DateTime MondayStart { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a `DisplayFormatAttribute` to your property and specify the `DataFormatString` property.

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:HH:mm}")]
public DateTime MondayStart { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `DisplayFormat` for your property:

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{HH:mm}")]
public DateTime MondayStart { get; set; }
```

Or you can create a DisplayTemplate:

```
@model DateTime?
if (Model.HasValue)
{
    @Model.ToString("HH:mm")
}
```